# Use of unresolved identifier for generated INIntent classes

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I created an intent definition that generates corresponding classes and protocols automatically.

Using the generated classes then cause the 'Use of unresolved identifier' error, however when I right-click on the generated class that's unresolved and select 'Jump to definition' Xcode seems to be busy for a short while and then displays the generated implementation.

The intent definition is not part of all the targets in the project, but this error occurs even if I check all targets that the project contains.
As you might expect, once I build the target there is no issue and the app is executing fine.

Cleaning and restarting also does not make any difference.

I am not sure where else I can check for to remedy this issue.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: No. Since it doesn't fail the build it's not a blocker but still an inconvenience...